# if the user click on button then the database table is created in database through asp.net with c#,how can do?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is that if the user click on button (which is place in default.aspx, for example) then the database table is created in database (SQL express), how can do that?

I have tried but errors are occuring during debugging, errors are:

1. `the best overloaded method match for 'system.data.odbc.odbc command.odbc command(string,system.data.odbc.odbc connection)'has some invalid arguments.`
2. `Argument'2':cannot convert from 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection' to 'system.data.odbc.odbc connection'.`

The code written in c# behind the button (button is placed in default.aspx, for example) is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
//using PractiseWeb.DataSet1TableAdapters;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using ADOX;
using ADODB;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
      SqlConnection conn;
      OdbcCommand cmd;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
{

   conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  if (!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 
    } 
    string sql = "CREATE TABLE mySchoolRecord(StudentId INTEGER CONSTRAINT PkeyMyId PRIMARY KEY,"
    + "Name CHAR(50)," + "Address CHAR(255)," + "Contact INTEGER));"; 
    cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql,conn);// in this line above two errors occurred
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (1, 'Mr. Manish', " + " 'Sector-12,Noida', 2447658  );";
    cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql,conn);// in this line above two errors occurred
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (2, 'Mr. Ravi', " + " 'New Delhi', 2584076521   );"; 
    cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql,conn);// in this line above two errors occurred
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (3, 'Mr. Peter', " + " 'United States', 25684124  );"; 
    cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql,conn);// in this line above two errors occurred
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 


    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
    { 
        conn.Close(); 
    } 

} 
catch (OdbcException ex) 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(ex); 
} 

    }
}
```

Comment: It is not preferred to create DB tables from Application Views. Always create DB, Schemas and Relations in DAtabases, instead of handling stuff from Front End Apps. Just a Suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing ADO (SQLConnection) and ODBC (ODBCCommand). Use [SQLCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28VS.71%29.aspx) instead if you're using SQL Server, or [ODBCCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection%28VS.80%29.aspx) if you're not. You can't mix the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
//using PractiseWeb.DataSet1TableAdapters;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using ADOX;
using ADODB;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
      SqlConnection conn;
      OdbcCommand cmd;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
{

   conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  if (!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 
    } 
    string sql = "CREATE TABLE mySchoolRecord(StudentId INTEGER CONSTRAINT PkeyMyId PRIMARY KEY,"
    + "Name CHAR(50)," + "Address CHAR(255)," + "Contact INTEGER));"; 
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);// in this line above two errors occurred
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (1, 'Mr. Manish', " + " 'Sector-12,Noida', 2447658  );";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);// in this line above two errors occurred
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (2, 'Mr. Ravi', " + " 'New Delhi', 2584076521   );"; 
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);// in this line above two errors occurred
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (3, 'Mr. Peter', " + " 'United States', 25684124  );"; 
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);// in this line above two errors occurred
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 


    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
    { 
        conn.Close(); 
    } 

} 
catch (OdbcException ex) 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(ex); 
} 

    }
}
```

Replacing OdbcCommand by SqlCommand will solve your problem

Comment: sir, i do that,odbc command replace by sqlcommand ,errors are removed but no table is created in the database(within sql express),please sir solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public object connection()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnectionString = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        double[] a = new double[6];
        string myCommand = null;
        myCommand = "CREATE database soft_billing";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString);
        try {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++) {
                a(k) = 0.0;
            }
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            t.Enabled = true;
            t.Interval = 10;
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0;

            cmd.Connection.Close();

        } catch {
            Interaction.MsgBox(" Already installed database", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, " MaS InfoTech- Warning");

        }
        try {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=soft_billing;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            string sql = null;
            sql = "CREATE TABLE customer(cus_name varchar(50) NULL,address varchar(50) NULL,mobno numeric(18, 0) NULL,tin varchar(50) NULL,kg varchar(50) NULL)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            // , connection);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();

        } catch {
            Interaction.MsgBox(" Already installed database", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, " MaS InfoTech- Warning");

        }
    }
```